# Performance of a T-sql query retrieving data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
 DECLARE  @table TABLE( mnbr int,
  Pid int,
  Pname varchar(10),
  Jid int,
  Jname varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES(150 ,    1   ,    'Mark'   ,   8    ,'Jerry')
,(250  ,   1  ,     'Mark'   ,   8    ,  'Jerry')
,(350  ,   2   ,    'Jim'     ,    9  ,   'Luke')
,(450  ,   2   ,    'Jim'     ,    9   ,  'Luke')
,(550  ,   2   ,    'Jim'     ,    10  ,  'Jude')
,(650  ,   3   ,    'Andy'   ,   11   , 'Matt')
,(750   ,  4   ,    'Brian'   ,    21  ,  'Chris')
,(850   ,  4   ,    'Brian'   ,     7  ,    'Mac')
,(950   ,  5   ,    'Jean '   ,    21   , 'Chris')
```

For the above data..... My output should be as shown below:

```
350    2      Jim     9    Luke
450    2      Jim     9    Luke
550    2      Jim     10   Jude
750    4      Brian   21   Chris
850    4      Brian   7      Mac
```

In the case of mnbr 150 and 250.... The primary owner mark has two joint accounts and on both joint accounts the joint owner is jerry. So Mark's accounts should not be displayed.

In the case if mnbr: 350, 450, 550

Jim has 3 joint accounts and not all the three joint accounts belong to the same joint owner. So all 3 accounts have to be displayed.

Mnbr 650 has only one joint account with one joint owner. So it should not be displayed.

I have written the following query that returns the data I require.

```
SELECT  * FROM @table WHERE pname IN (
SELECT   pname FROM @table
    WHERE pname  IN (SELECT pname FROM @table GROUP BY pname,jname HAVING COUNT(*)!>1)
 GROUP BY pname HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
```

I would like to know, is my query going to provide good performance?

Comment: What is the SPECIFIC issue you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the query slightly to

```
SELECT *
FROM   @table
WHERE  pname IN (SELECT   pname
                 FROM     @table
                 GROUP BY pname
                 HAVING   MAX(jid) <> MIN(jid));
```

Whether that would perform better or not is something you would need to test against a much larger data set than the one you provided in your question.

In this case, the more important factor in running either query against a larger data set would more likely be to have an index on either a combination of the pname, jname fields or the pname, jid fields.

Assuming a table name of 'accounts' a helpfull index might look something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_accounts_pname_jid] ON [dbo].[accounts] 
(
    [pname] ASC,
    [jid] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
```